# ImportError: No module named pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, database-connection, pyodbc

I downloaded the pyodbc module as a zip and installed it manually using the command `python setup.py install`. Although I can find the folder inside the Python directory which I pasted, while importing I am getting the error:

`ImportError: No module named pyodbc`

I am trying to use to this to connect with MS SQL Server. Help

Comment: Why not using pip instead? it is recommended in its documentation: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Install

Comment: I am working in office and there are proxies setup. So, pip calls fail because of a `ProxyError`

Comment: did `setup.py install` gave any warning or error? Try reinstalling

Comment: Yeah. I just noticed. This is the error: `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat). Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27`

Comment: Just download and install it, then try to install pyodbc again and check if that solves problem

Comment: Yeah just did. It is installed. Thanks

Comment: Ok, added solution as an answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As installation error showed, installing Visual C++ 9.0 solves problem because `setup.py` tries to compile some C++ libraries while installing plugin. I thing Cygwin C++ will also work due to contents of `setup.py`.